# How to remove blank header

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm designing a website for my company and we're using a wordpress template. We've been able to modify the template to make it full screen (& full width), however, we can't get rid of the blank header that is seen in the screen shot below. We've added custom CSS style into our style sheet, which has helped, but did not eliminate the problem:

CSS Style we added:

```
.page-template-template-fullsize-php #header { margin-bottom: 0; }
```

Any other advice would be very helpful as we're looking to clean up this aesthetic flaw on our website.

Screenshot:

[image]
Website Address: http://visualicreative.com/products/advertising/web-commercial-html/

Comment: We'll need to see a complete code example. The one line of CSS and image aren't enough.

Comment: Please remove php tag, this question has nothing to do with php

Comment: My problem has been fixed. A huge thanks to everyone who aided me with this question. Never thought in a million years that I would get so many answers, so quickly. Definitely going to recommend this site to my friends and use it more in the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help your CSS:

```
#content .entry-header {
display:none;
}
#content {
padding: 0px 30px 30px 30px;
} 
/*changed from padding:30px; */
```

You really need to tweak your theme. You've got a lot of blank code in there that is creating gaps (including the blank header).

You have some inline code that increases top padding:

```
<div id="main" class="clearfix zIndex" style="padding-top: 108px;">
```

Then all of this under the entry content:

```
<p><a name="top"></a></p>
```

Comment: Airbrean,

Thank you for your response - it helped fix most of the issue!

In your response your referred to "<div id="main" class="clearfix zIndex" style="padding-top: 108px;">"... Is this something I can change in my CSS style sheet or do I have to go into the template editor to edit it?

Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: You would just have to override the padding-top in CSS for the div and label it as important. `#main {padding-top:0px !important;}`

Comment: That's what we're here for @Jeffrey9896 :)

Answer (score 0):

For your article directive/element if you use `margin-top: -100px;` you can shift it up by 100 pixels. More [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp).

Answer (score 0):

In one of your template files that has been used on that page, there is a

`<header class="entry-header">
    <h1 class="entry-title"></h1>
</header>`

empty header which causes a little more space. The rest of that additional space is because possibly in the same file just one line up of your header element, you have an `<article>` element with the id of `#content` which has `padding:30px;`

You can change that padding style to

```
padding: 0px 30px 30px 30px;
```

just to get rid of the top padding.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have 108px of padding at the top of `div#main.clearfix.zIndex`. By removing or lessening that padding, you can affect how close to the menu bar your main div is.

Answer (score 0):

Change the padding of `.nav-full-width #main` and you are good to go. also `.entry-header` has a margin, change that too.

Answer (score 0):

I visited that web page and I recognized to there is many different type of levels to header.You can fix and delete some of them.However, there is a one way to fix,You should insert #content css veraible to `padding-top:0px;`.Also, you should delete unnececarry div and p lines from pure html.One of the unneccecary code line is in the following segment;

```
<header class="entry-header">
  <h1 class="entry-title"></h1>
</header>
```

More over, there 2 empty `p` tags on the pure html.You should delete them.I tried it on the browser and it displaying,whatever you like.